# Use TOML vesion file in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, toml

I try use version from libs.versions.toml to set composeOptions like this:

```
android {
 ...
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion.get()
    }
}
```

But I get error with `.get()` function :

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable
> because of receiver type mismatch: public inline operator fun <K, V>
> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.get(key: TypeVariable(K)):
> TypeVariable(V)? defined in kotlin.collections public operator fun
> MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in
> kotlin.text

TOML versioning working well when a use this to apply plugins and implement libraries but not working when I want to get a version with `.get()`

Gradle version 7.5.1

Comment: Could you please share version block of `libs.versions.toml`?

Answer (score 5):

toml file `MyProject/gradle/libs.versions.toml`:

```
[versions]
minSdk = "24"
kotlinVersion = "1.8.21"#https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin
[libraries]
kotlinStdlibJdk8 = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8", version.ref = "kotlinVersion" }
```

In gradle use: `libs.versions.kotlinVersion.get()`, for example:

```
minSdk libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInteger()
...
dependencies {
    
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${libs.versions.kotlinVersion.get()}"
    implementation libs.kotlinStdlibJdk8

}
```

[See documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html)

Comment: Use `.toInteger()` if an integer value is required. Ex: `minSdk libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInteger()`

Answer (score 1):

If you get `Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable receiver type mismatch...` when you are trying to get a version of library `xxx` from your [Gradle Version Catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) via `.get()` method, in 99% of cases it means that you have library `xxx-yyy` in your `[versions]` block, e.g.

```ini
[versions]

kotlin = "1.7.20"
kotlin-coroutines = "1.6.4"
kotlin-serialization = "1.4.1"
```

In that case Gradle won't generate regular `Provider` for the field `libs.versions.kotlin` (in the example), it generates more complex object, because it has to generate `libs.versions.kotlin.coroutines`, `libs.versions.kotlin.serialization` fields.

That's why if you want to get library version you have to explicitly ask for provider using `.asProvider()` before getter `.get()`:

```kotlin
libs.versions.kotlin.asProvider().get()
```

and for library in question it will be:

```kotlin
libs.versions.kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion.asProvider().get()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer:

If your libs.versions.toml is like below

```ini
[versions]
compose = "1.4.3"
compose-compiler = "1.4.7"
```

then you should use

```
composeOptions {
  kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion libs.versions.compose.compiler.get()
}
```

#### Long answer:

Gradle will generate a `LibrariesForLibs` class based on the `libs.versions.toml` file, which you can find in the `.gradle/7.5/dependencies-accessors/sources` folder in the project root path.

For example, the toml mentioned above would generate code as follows:

```java
@NonNullApi
public class LibrariesForLibs extends AbstractExternalDependencyFactory {
    @Inject
    public LibrariesForLibs(DefaultVersionCatalog config, ProviderFactory providers) {
        super(config, providers);
    }
    private final VersionAccessors vaccForVersionAccessors = new VersionAccessors(providers, config);
    /**
     * Returns the group of versions at versions
     */
    public VersionAccessors getVersions() { return vaccForVersionAccessors; }
    public static class VersionAccessors extends VersionFactory  {
        private final ComposeVersionAccessors vaccForComposeVersionAccessors = new ComposeVersionAccessors(providers, config);
        public VersionAccessors(ProviderFactory providers, DefaultVersionCatalog config) { super(providers, config); }
        /**
         * Returns the group of versions at versions.compose
         */
        public ComposeVersionAccessors getCompose() { return vaccForComposeVersionAccessors; }
    }
    public static class ComposeVersionAccessors extends VersionFactory  implements VersionNotationSupplier {
        public ComposeVersionAccessors(ProviderFactory providers, DefaultVersionCatalog config) { super(providers, config); }
        /**
         * Returns the version associated to this alias: compose (1.4.3)
         * If the version is a rich version and that its not expressible as a
         * single version string, then an empty string is returned.
         * This version was declared in catalog libs.versions.toml
         */
        public Provider<String> asProvider() {return getVersion("compose");}

        /**
         * Returns the version associated to this alias: compose.compiler (1.4.7)
         * If the version is a rich version and that its not expressible as a
         * single version string, then an empty string is returned.
         * This version was declared in catalog libs.versions.toml
         */
        public Provider<String> getCompiler() {return getVersion("compose.compiler");}
    }
}
```

When you use the `libs` variable in gradle.build, you are actually accessing an instance object of `LibrariesForLibs`. So if you want to get the version of `compose-compiler`, you need to call `libs.getVersions().getCompose().getCompiler().get()` , and `groovy` has built-in `getter` syntactic sugar, so we can write more elegant code `libs.versions.compose.compiler.get()`

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95EDr.jpg)

Comment: In Android Studio, for `libs.versions.toml` the compose-compiler version line shows up as unused. How to correct that?